# How to install a Python Module from Source without pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial

I have a system with Python 3.5 installed and it has no ether net or wifi connectivity.It doesnt have pip either.
I wanted to install the pyserial . I have downloaded it : https://pypi.org/project/pyserial/#files ( there were two options - wheel and source , i picked source and downloaded it and transferred it via usb)
Regards,

Comment: Hey, are you using a Linux machine?

Comment: yes i am on linux

Comment: I think Giordano's answer should be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unpack the archive, enter the pyserial-x.y directory and run:

```
 python setup.py install
```

Using the python/python3 executable of the desired version (2.7/3.x).

Information taken from [here](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/master/documentation/pyserial.rst#from-source-ziptargz-or-checkout).

Comment: getting this : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py_compile'

Comment: i am on this python  : python3 --version
Python 3.8.2

Comment: ok this is fixed by downloading https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/py_compile.py inside ls -l /usr/lib/python3.8 . I see some embedded systems dosnt have it.Mine was one case.

Comment: yes it is .But its hard to download the relevant dependencies since there are many versions of python.But hopefully it works now.Thumb rule is to always download the source and install using the command you mentioned above